# Does this count as predicate transfer?

Tags: morphology

Yesterday, I asked the meaning of some phrases in this [Wikipedia article on predicate transer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_transfer) on [English language and usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299284/what-does-i-am-parked-out-back-mean-in-this-paragraph?), assuming that I didn't understand the article because of those phrases. I got some comments answering on a phrase I didn't understand, but then one commenter mentioned that the article itself is confusing. So I decided to ask if I understand this concept right here.

Does this count as another example of predicate transfer?: "I still don't get that joke." The object of the sentence rules out the other meanings of "get" and we're left with only one meaning "understand".

The article is pretty short:

> In linguistics, predicate transfer[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_transfer) is the reassignment of a
>   property to an object which would not otherwise inherently have that
>   property. Thus, the expression "I am parked out back" conveys the
>   meaning of "parked" from "car" to the property of "I possess a car".
>   This avoids incorrect polysemous interpretations of "parked": that
>   "people can be parked", or that "I am pretending to be a car", or that
>   "I am something which can be parked". This is supported by the
>   morphology: "We are parked out back" does not mean that there are
>   multiple cars; rather, that there are multiple passengers (having the
>   property of being in possession of a car).

Comment: Perhaps not, since there is no transfer of meaning from one object to another. "Get" is constant in regards with who does the "getting" such that "I" in "I don't get the joke" does not refer to some other entity, unlike the "I" in "I'm parked out back", which refers to a car.

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "predicate transfer": I would describe the example in the text as _synecdoche_.